# Windows phone Add item above applicationbar

Tags: windows-phone

I want to add a menu to my app that shows up slightly above the application bar.  The items are not needed all the time so I don't want them on the app bar.  is there a way to find the location of the top of the app bar so that I can use that as a reference to set my other menu?

Comment: You obviously have to implement this yourself.  Couldn't you create a User Control and set the VerticalAlignment="Bottom" in XAML?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to do what you are saying, have a look at the app bar properties events and functions on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff431813%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_ApplicationBarUserInterface